# FileNotFoundError when unpickling multiple files within a folder

Tags: python, pickle, filenotfounderror

I am currently trying to unpickle multiple individually pickled files that exist within a folder.

As there are around 600 individual pickled files I'd like to be able to iterate through the folder instead of manually unpickling each file.

#### Code

```py
data_dirA = 'Data/FolderA'

for img in os.listdir(data_dirA):
    with open(img,'rb') as f:
        pickle.load(f)
```

#### Error

Raises a `FileNotFoundError` in Jupyter Notebook:

```
      1 for img in os.listdir(data_dirA):
----> 2     with open(img,'rb') as f:
      3         pickle.loads(f)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.pck'
```

#### What I tried

I have been able to avoid the above PATH error using:

```py
with open("Data/FolderA/1.pck", "rb") as f:
    img = pck.load(f)
```

But this unfortunately only works for a single file and must be manually changed between files. (Although this still does throw an unpickling error stating that: 'pickle data was truncated', but that seems out of the scope of this question).

#### Note

I should also add that I am aware of how to iterate through and open multiple files. My challenge here is that as I understand unpickling must be performed on files based on their name (please correct me if I have misunderstood as I don't see any threads that directly answer this question).

#### EDIT

with Answer Code:

```
for root, _, files in os.walk('Data/Intact'):
for content in files:
    if not content.endswith('.pkl'):
        continue

    print(f"\n{root}/{content} data:")
    with open(f"{root}/{content}", 'r') as f:
        while 1:
            try:
                print(pickle.load(f))
            except EOFError:
                break
```

Comment: I suppose you also read the docs for [`pickle.loads(data)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=data#pickle.loads) and the required type of a [bytes-lie object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object). Then it might be an issue with the file-path, existence of the file or the file-opening.

Comment: Hi, yes I have read those. Unfortunately pickle.loads provides the same directory error as above. The PATH I am using (data_dirA) is the PATH that jupyter lab provides me with when I scroll to the individual files I want unpickled and click copy PATH (without the individual file included because I'm hoping to iterate the unpickling instead of to unpickle one file.

Comment: When opening an absolute file path works, but opening the file-name only doesn't, then it might help to construct an absolute path for each name in `img`. See return of [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=names#os.listdir): "names of the entries in the directory given by path". Could also use [`pathlib.Path.iterdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) like `for child in Path('/home/user/Downloads').iterdir(): child`

Comment: You are in directory X and have asked for the list of files in directory Y and then expecting to open them. Either change directory to where you are looking or construct the full path rather than a relative path. Or, said another way... you are in **Park Drive** and have asked for all files in **Pine Avenue**. You are told there's a `1.pkl` in **Pine Avenue** but expecting to open it at **1 Park Drive**.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect all your files are in `FolderA` and have file extension `.pck`.

Use `file_name.endswith(('.pck','.pkl',....)):` to validate file type to be pickle and continue to next step to read its content.

> Your pickle load worries me, as it loads only the last serialized pickle object. Try this instead.

```
while True:
    try:
        data.append(pickle.load(file_obj))
    except EOFError:
        break
print(data)
```

> error - pickle data was truncated

You data stream is corrupted and you should get the whole file to be pickled properly again.

There are 6 protocols which can be used for pickling. Your python version should match for pickling and unpickling above lowest orders.

*Example: you get error while unpickling protocol 5 file in python 3.5.*

---

**Sample code:**

```
for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
    for content in files:
        if not content.endswith('.pkl'):
            continue

        print(f"\n{root}/{content} data:")
        with open(f"{root}/{content}", 'r') as f:
            while 1:
                try:
                    print(pickle.load(f))
                except EOFError:
                    break
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. While I don't get an error from this code, it also isn't seeming to return anything. I have added my understanding of how to apply this sample code to the original question.

Comment: Can you confirm, if all required pickled file extensions in `Data/Intact` to end with `.pkl`. Earlier you mentioned them to end with `.pck`. If any other extension, just add them to the file extension check `content.endswith((...))`.

Comment: Further debug to find what file types are being skipped if extension addition doesn't work.